# Отметить checkbox при переходе по ссылке

Tags: php, javascript, html

Есть список ссылок, которые ведут каждая на свою страницу. На каждой целевой странице есть форма с кучей чекбоксов.
Подскажите как сделать чтобы при переходе на страницу в форме отмечался необходимый чексбокс.

Я передаю параметры `GET` и могу его получить из адресной строки на целевой странице, а вот как уже найти чекбокса нужный мне и его отметить?

Может как-то по `name` найти?

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=select+element+by+name+attribute

Answer (score 1):

Допустим Вы уже получаете get параметр, к примеру ссылка имеет такой вид 
`<a href="/page?checked=notice">`.

На целевой странице есть элемент:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="notice">
```

В данном случае JS код будет таким:

```
function autoCheck(){

var checked = getParameterByName('checked'); //получаем значение get параметра checked

if (!checked) return;

var target = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="'+  checked +'"]');

if (!target) return;

target.checked = true;

}
```

Comment: А куда нужно записать эту функцию? на страницу с чекбоксом?

Comment: Да, на страницу с чекбоксом