# Отметить checkbox при переходе по ссылке не работает

Tags: javascript, html

знаю что здесь уже был этот вопрос но не знаю почему тот ответ([Отметить checkbox при переходе по ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559340/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-checkbox-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5)) не сработал у меня 
вот мой код страницы с которой мы будем переходить

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="test3.html?checked=doyou">1 chek</a>
<a href="test3.html?checked=helpm">2 chek</a>
</body>
</html>
```

вот код самой страницы с checkbox на которую мы переходим

```
<html>
<body>

<script defer>
function autoCheck(){
var checked = getParameterByName('checked');
if (!checked) return;
var target = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="'+  checked +'"]');
if (!target) return;
target.checked = true;
}
</script> 


<input type="checkbox" name="doyou">1
<input type="checkbox" name="helpm">2

</body>
</html>
```

что я сделал не так или этот способ уже не работает?

Comment: Объявить - объявили, вызвать забыли. Надо еще вызывать функцию `autoCheck();` вроде остальное должно работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, вы определяете функцию, но не вызываете ее. Во-вторых функции **getParameterByName** не существует.
Вот пример кода, который должен работать.
Небольшое замечание, не работает в старых браузерах.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility
 если нужна их поддержка, то можно использовать полифил https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill

```html
<html>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" name="doyou">1
<input type="checkbox" name="helpm">2

<script defer>
function autoCheck(){
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const checked = urlParams.get("checked");
  if (!checked) {
    return;
  }
  var target = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="'+  checked +'"]');
  if (!target) {
    return;
  }
  target.checked = true;
}
autoCheck();
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

или второй вариант без **URLSearchParams**

```html
<html>
<body>


<input type="checkbox" name="doyou">1
<input type="checkbox" name="helpm">2

<script defer>
function autoCheck(){
  const checked = window.location.href.match(/\?.*?checked=([a-z]+)/) || [0, 0][1];
  if (!checked) {
    return;
  }
  var target = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][name="'+  checked +'"]');
  if (!target) {
    return;
  }
  target.checked = true;
}
autoCheck();
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А не проще `...href.match(/\?.*?checked=([a-z]+)/)` во втором варианте?

Comment: Согласен, поправил.

Comment: `[1]` таки выдаст ошибку, если вернется null. Можно `= ( ...match(/.../) || [0,0] )[1]`

Comment: не знаю почему не тот ни другой код не работает и вообще у вас почему то на одной странице и сама ссылка и чекбокс хотя у меня они на разных

Comment: Попробуй вот так.

Comment: да сработало, спасибо большое

Comment: Просто функция выполнялась, а в доме еще не было чекбоксов. Пожалуйста.